# Validation on key-press

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following WPF code to validate key-press and based on the key pressed it either allows user to enter the key or simply stops the key press event to stop entering invalid keys..

```
<TextBox PreviewKeyDown="PreviewKeyDown" />
```

```
private void PortPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    bool allowedKeys;
    allowedKeys = // logic for validation

    e.Handled = allowedKeys;
}
```

My question is, is this the right approach to do validation in WPF.. I want to restrict user to enter invalid character..

I know I can use dependency properties and call validation and then display error or success message, but I don't want to get that far, I simply want to stop user from entering invalid characters.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a valid approach to me, however I would try to display some message telling the user when a character is invalid, otherwise they might think something is broken.

It might also be a good idea to make the logic generic by subclassing `TextBox` and providing properties which characters are allowed. Some libraries already have controls like this, like the [`MaskedTextBox`](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MaskedTextBox) of the extended WPF toolkit which also provides format highlighting.